# Mac application update from dmg

Tags: macos, cocoa

Currently I am developing a MacOSX app. it can be launch at startup. So it has launchitem installed.
However, when I need to update app, I drag app to ./Applications from dmg dialog window to replace current app with updated one.

Click the updated one, then reboot my Mac. Mac still show the previous app. It seems like I don't really replace or overwrite the old app.

Does anyone know how to clean the previous launch item and files when users drag new app from dmg to ./Applications ?

Thanks

Comment: Where does this app being launched really live?  In `/Applications` or in `/Library/StartupItems` ?

Comment: Both /Applications /Library/StartupItems~~ I am thinking about installer/package not simple dmg for drag-and-drop.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is there is one deprecated app archive folder in user/developer/xcode/archive/, which is first triggered by launchitem. So the update app in applications is not called.